# Display an expression as a string in Scheme

Tags: scheme

```
(define (display_input_as_entered input)
    (display input)
)

(display_input_as_entered (+ 3 3 2 4))
```

Here, I tried to create a function that displays the expression that is entered as input, instead of displaying the result of the expression. I wanted `(display_input_as_entered (+ 3 3 2 4))` to print `(+ 3 3 2 4)`, but it printed `12` instead. Is it possible to make the function behave as expected, without making any changes to its input?

I'm aware that it's impossible to do this in most programming languages, but I suspect that it may be possible in Scheme somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A macro will do the trick here. For example, in Racket:

```
(define-syntax display_input_as_entered
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ exp) 'exp)))

(display_input_as_entered (+ 3 3 2 4))
=> '(+ 3 3 2 4)
```

Comment: I tried running this in guile, and got `ERROR: Unbound variable: define-syntax`. Which Scheme dialect is this code written in?

Comment: It's Racket - sorry, I should have mentioned it. Check your interpreter's documentation for the correct macro syntax, but the idea will be the same.

Comment: It is not exclusively Racket (they didn't invent 'define-syntax'); it is R5RS, R6RS and R7RS.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any documentation for the `_` symbol in Racket. What does this symbol mean?

Comment: @AndersonGreen it's a placeholder for the name of the macro. In the above code you can replace `_` with `display_input_as_entered` and it'll work just the same

Answer (score 4):

What you are searching for is quote.

```
(quote (+ 3 3 2 4)) ; ==> (+ 3 3 2 4)
```

Since it's so widely used it's got an abbreviation:

```
'(+ 3 3 2 4) ; ==> (+ 3 3 2 4)
```

**Trivia:** `quote` has been with LISP from it's very beginning and it's on [page 131 of the LISP 1 programmers manual](http://history.siam.org/sup/Fox_1960_LISP.pdf).